# How can I get to the end of a specific child which has different edited key

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Example Data Model:

[image: Example Data Model]

I am trying to get the position of the child so that every time I click the items, I can edit the data. I am using a Recycler Adapter by the way.

How can I get to the end of a specific child which has different edited key?

```
mDatabaseReferenceAttendance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Attendance").child("Record");
mDatabaseReferenceAttendance.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.exists()){
            for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
                
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

    }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "How can I get to the end of a specific child
"?

Comment: I encircled the image above. That is where I want to get the child

Comment: Read in all the data, then filter client side?

Comment: Yes. I need to read all the data so that I can edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code reads all data under `Attendance/Record`. If you want to show the data for `John-Smith` on `April 10, 2022-test` (and similar nodes), you can loop over the extra levels in your JSON with:

```
mDatabaseReferenceAttendance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Attendance").child("Record");
mDatabaseReferenceAttendance.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot dateSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
            for(DataSnapshot userSnapshot : dateSnapshot.getChildren()){
                System.out.println(userSnapshot.getKey()); // "John-Smith"
                System.out.println(userSnapshot.child("description").getValue(String.class)); // "test"
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        throw error.toException(); // never ignore errors
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Now, the problem is the position. I want to go to the key April 10, 2022-test and I only get the data of the last key of the node.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that problem. The code in my answer should print all keys and descriptions under `Attendance/Record` in the JSON in your screenshot. Does it not do that when you run it?

Comment: I ran it again with the description. The keys are working is show's April 10, 2022-test but Description show's null.

Comment: That's unexpected. Does it show `"John-Smith"`?

Comment: Nope. Just April 10, 2022-test. Anyway, what I did was I switch the name and date node. I then got the key which is now John-Smith. Then use the intent to throw the key to another activity then use it with another Firebase Recycler Adapter which now works.